# How to install oci8 with only an instant client using pecl

Tags: apache2, php, oracle

I am trying to compile OCI8 for PHP

```
sudo pecl install ./oci8-2.2.0.tgz
```

Asks me oracle for the path to the roacle home folder,
but I get the following error "Checking ORACLE_HOME library validity... configure: error: Exrected an ORACLE_HOME top-level directory but /usr/local/lib/oracle/instantclient appears to be an Instant Client directory. Try --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/local/lib/oracle/instantclient

I tried

```
sudo pecl install ./oci8-2.2.0.tgz  --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/local/lib/oracle/instantclien
```

But also got an error.

How do I properly install OCI8 using pecl? (sadly I cannot use binary package apt install)

Answer (score 1):

First extract it .tgz file.

If you have one file in .tgz compress, just double-click it.
İf you have more files in .tgz and you have "configure" file in folder

Type in folder (terminal):

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If you have runable .sh file in folder

Type in folder (terminal):

```
./bla-bla.sh
```